# Coroutine StateFlow stops emitting when CoroutineScope is cancelled

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `StateFlow` coroutine that is shared amongst various parts of my application. When I `cancel` the `CoroutineScope` of a downstream collector, a `JobCancellationException` is propagated up to the `StateFlow`, and it stops emitting values for all current and future collectors.

The `StateFlow`:

```
val songsRelay: Flow<List<Song>> by lazy {
    MutableStateFlow<List<Song>?>(null).apply {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
            .launch { songDataDao.getAll().distinctUntilChanged().collect { value = it } }
    }.filterNotNull()
}
```

A typical 'presenter' in my code implements the following base class:

```
abstract class BasePresenter<T : Any> : BaseContract.Presenter<T> {

    var view: T? = null

    private val job by lazy {
        Job()
    }

    private val coroutineScope by lazy { CoroutineScope( job + Dispatchers.Main) }

    override fun bindView(view: T) {
        this.view = view
    }

    override fun unbindView() {
        job.cancel()
        view = null
    }

    fun launch(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
        return coroutineScope.launch(block = block)
    }
}
```

A `BasePresenter` implementation might call `launch{ songsRelay.collect {...} }`
When the presenter is unbound, in order to prevent leaks, I cancel the parent job. Any time a presenter that was collecting the `songsRelay` `StateFlow` is unbound, the `StateFlow` is essentially terminated with a `JobCancellationException`, and no other collectors/presenters can collect values from it.

I've noticed that I can call `job.cancelChildren()` instead, and this seems to work (`StateFlow` doesn't complete with a `JobCancellationException`). But then I wonder what the point is of declaring a parent `job`, if I can't cancel the job itself. I could just remove `job` altogether, and call `coroutineScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()` to the same effect.

If I do just call `job.cancelChildren()`, is that sufficient? I feel like by not calling `coroutineScope.cancel()`, or `job.cancel()`, I may not be correctly or completely cleaning up the tasks that I have kicked off.

I also don't understand why the `JobCancellationException` is propagated up the hierarchy when `job.cancel()` is called. Isn't `job` the 'parent' here? Why does cancelling it affect my `StateFlow`?

Comment: I played around with this a bit, made a small unit test trying to reproduce your behavior. But I was unable to get the `JobCancellationException`. I'm just starting out with coroutines+flow after a few years of RxJava, so maybe I'm missing something.
Can you share a self-contained example reproducing the issue?

Comment: Yeah, it may well be that there's something else at play here. I'll see if I can reproduce the issue in Kotlin playgrounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Are you sure your `songRelay` is actually getting cancelled for all presenters? I ran this test and "Song relay completed" is printed, because `onCompletion` also catches downstream exceptions. However Presenter 2 emits the value 2 just fine, AFTER song relay prints "completed". If I cancel Presenter 2, "Song relay completed" is printed again with a JobCancellationException for Presenter 2's job.

I do find it interesting how the one flow instance will emit once each for each collector subscribed. I didn't realize that about flows.

```
    val songsRelay: Flow<Int> by lazy {
        MutableStateFlow<Int?>(null).apply {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
                    .launch {
                        flow {
                            emit(1)
                            delay(1000)
                            emit(2)
                            delay(1000)
                            emit(3)
                        }.onCompletion {
                            println("Dao completed")
                        }.collect { value = it }
                    }
        }.filterNotNull()
                .onCompletion { cause ->
                    println("Song relay completed: $cause")
                }
    }

    @Test
    fun test() = runBlocking {
        val job = Job()
        val presenterScope1 = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Unconfined)
        val presenterScope2 = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Unconfined)

        presenterScope1.launch {
            songsRelay.onCompletion { cause ->
                println("Presenter 1 Completed: $cause")
            }.collect {
                println("Presenter 1 emits: $it")
            }
        }

        presenterScope2.launch {
            songsRelay.collect {
                println("Presenter 2 emits: $it")
            }
        }

        presenterScope1.cancel()

        delay(2000)
        println("Done test")
    }
```

I think you need to use [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html) in your BasePresenter instead of `Job`. In general using `Job` would be a mistake for the whole presenter, because one failed coroutine will cancel all coroutines in the Presenter. Generally not what you want.

Comment: You may be right - SupervisorJob might be a better fit. But this doesn't really answer the question (and replacing Job with SupervisorJob does not solve the issue)

Comment: Updated my answer. I can't reproduce in tests what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I think that there must be something else at play, I'm still investigating. It might be that the premise of this question is invalid

Comment: I've just had a chance to come back to this. So - no, the flow wasn't getting cancelled for all presenters. My test to replicate was flawed - I was unbinding then rebinding the same presenter, and it was on the second bind that the flow stopped collecting - because `cancel()` had been called - which is expected behaviour. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem was some false assumptions I made when testing this. The StateFlow is behaving correctly, and cancellation is working as expected.

I was thinking that between `Presenters`, `StateFlow` would stop emitting values, but I was actually testing the same instance of a `Presenter` - so its `Job` had been cancelled and thus it's not expected to continue collecting Flow emissions.

I also mistakenly took `CancellationException` messages emitted in `onCompletion` of the `StateFlow` to mean the `StateFlow` itself had been cancelled - when actually it was just saying the downstream `Collector`/`Job` had been cancelled.

I've come up with a better implementation of `BasePresenter` that looks like so:

```
abstract class BasePresenter<T : Any> : BaseContract.Presenter<T>, CoroutineScope {

    var view: T? = null

    private var job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun bindView(view: T) {
        if (job.isCancelled) {
            job = Job()
        }
        this.view = view
    }

    override fun unbindView() {
        job.cancel()
        view = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I would still recommend using SupervisorJob here though. For someone using your `BasePresenter` they probably won't expect that when `launch { getApi1 }` fails, somewhere else where they've used `launch { getApi2 }` will also be cancelled.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm using a SupervisorJob for this myself, I just didn't want to introduce a new concept to the Q&A.

Comment: Always remember that StateFlow never completes. It is impossible to cancel it :)

Comment: @HarryTimothy so we can waste resources if we run several and never use them again? then probably it's ideal for cases where we need the data as long as the app is alive?